# How to retrieve default Title in custom module block

Tags: 7

I have custom module that implements a block with our own template file to render:

```
function MODULE_NAME_block_view($delta = ''){
    $blocks = array();
    switch($delta){
        case 'twitter_feed':{
            $blocks['subject'] = t('');
            $blocks['content'] = theme_render_template(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME').'/inc/block--twitter-feed.tpl.php', twitter_feed_config());
            break;
        }
    }
    return $blocks;
}
```

I would like to pass the title value set in UI in blocks section to the template via the function twitter_feed_config specified above as following:

```
function twitter_feed_config(){
  return array(
       'title' => 'title set by user i am unable to retrieve'
   );
}
```

However, I don't seem to find a way to retrieve the value of title for this block configured via UI in the admin/block section. How to get this title value, so i can pass it to the template for rendering? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [hook_block_views_alter(&$data, $block)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7).

Var `$data['subject'];` will have the title info of the block as per my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you Rajeev. This does not work for me because its parameters is array of data as returned from the hook_block_view() from a scope i need the 'title' accessible in first place.